# Cross platform for React Native

Tags: react-native

As I know the first priority of React Native is not cross platform. It claims **"learn once use everywhere"** instead of **"write once use everywhere"**. So there are a few specific components like StatusBarIOS, NavigatorIOS, AlertIOS. Although there are some cross platform alternative components like Navigator, StatusBar, etc, Facebook suggest us to use platform specific version for better performance.

But my question is why don't just wrap the platform specific version inside the universal version in the first place? For example, Navigator, why don't just use NavigatorIOS internally in iOS? Wouldn't it be nicer to keep the performance and make it cross platform at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by

> But my question is why don't just wrap the platform specific version inside the universal version in the first place?

I was trying to build a so called cross-platform app. But I ended up writing too many if-else blocks for rendering simplest of platform-specific components. I scrapped the whole app altogether, and tried using better folder structure instead.

I created an `src` folder in root of the application. And then divided the app into `api`, `views`, `components`. The `views` and `components` were further divided into `android` and `ios` folders. Inside `src` folder, I had a `main.js` which contained `Navigator`.

This is what I prefer to do! You might want to do something else. That's okay. At the end of this learning experience, I found that Facebook was right. it is not **write once use everywhere**. It is **learn once apply however you want!** As long as your app is delivering 60 FPS experience to your user, anything is valid in React Native.

Comment: What I mean is why don't Facebook just wrap everything inside React Native with a standard interface. For example, when you use Navigator in iOS, you'll actually use NavigatorIOS. Then we don't need any ***if***,***else*** in our code.

Comment: Nice enough idea to at least entertain. But navigator IOS no longer maintained by Facebook. Other components are platform specific so you can't possibly use it on unsupported platforms. Facebook has faith in programmers' common sense and hence the loose coupling of components.

Comment: Actually I see no difference in ***Alert*** and ***AlertIOS***. But ***Alert*** will be cross platform. If this is the case, why should we use ***AlertIOS*** or why should we even keep AlertIOS? Anyway thanks for your idea.

Comment: @bagusflyer Yes, I see your point very clearly. But imagine a scenario where alert in iOS consists of a prop called "title" and alert in Android does not support "title" prop. Programmer will have to keep in mind that Android alert does not have a title and then write the code accordingly. Similar issues may occur for components which may look same at the superficial level, but differ greatly in their details. So would it not be better to have Alert and AlertIOS as separate components?